# Hibernate Criteria paging

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way in JAVA hibernate to execute a criteria query and projections count on that same query in a single trip to the DB?

The reason for wanting this is getting the most efficient way to page results, i was hoping to do the following

```
start transaction 
   start db call
     do query()
     do count()
   end db call
end transaction
```

what i'm currently doing is

```
start transaction 
   start db call
     do query()
   end db call
   start db call
     do count()
   end db call
end transaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really looked into this about a year ago and the best I came up with was executing both database operations in the same transaction. It is still two separate database hits, but it eliminates somewhat embarrassing headers like records 1-50 from 45.

Comment: we're toying with the idea of just putting a next button if the results.count = 10 and if you end up with exactly say 40 records you'd end up with one page that says no more results found

Comment: @dstarh: better, increase the number of rows in a page to one more than you display, that way the number of rows returned tells you if there is another page of results to get.

Comment: The approach I described is working quite well on quite large tables. The most expensive part of this is the database executing 2 selects. Running them in one transaction just guarantees consistency. I'm not sure what do you mean when you say you want to do it in 1 db call vs. 2. I can assure you that if you perform such 2 queries in the same transaction/connection/Hibernate session, there's almost no other overhead to squeeze out.

Comment: @Nathan that's so obvious it's unobvious :) that sounds perfect - it lets you know if you show the next button without the count at all

Comment: Accepting this as it seems to be the only viable solution in java hibernate

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic question.  The short answer is no, as you need to actually determine the number of records, then you need to retrieve only those records you want for the page.  I've done this before by using the same `Criteria` query, but doing the following:

1. Set up the full `Criteria` query except for sorting, limit and offset
2. Add a `Projections.rowCount()` to the query, and execute the query using `uniqueResult()`
3. Set the `Projections` to `null`
4. Add the sorting (`addOrder`), limit (`setMaxResults`) and offset (`setFirstResult`)
5. Run the query again, this time using `list` to retrieve the resultset

Note that even when working inside a stored proc in Oracle, I've seen experienced DBAs do exactly the same thing.

Comment: actually if this were straight sql it is possible, notice I never said 1 query, I said one trip to the database, these are two different things.  Right now I'm doing it like you state but it's still a separate trip to the database with sql (likely vendor specific) it's possible for a single trip with multiple statements and getting multiple result sets back.

Comment: Good point.  If you want a single trip, then consider just using a stored proc which returns an array.  I'm not sure Hibernate was designed to handle what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The question is could you even formulate such a query in SQL? You might be able to come up with some crazy union that gets the count and the first page of results together, but I doubt the performance would be better than two queries and no, there would be no way for hibernate to automatically map this for you.

Comment: many databases allow you to do the following - select * from A; select * from B - it runs them both then returns 2 resultsets